# http_build_query replaces array key in result

Tags: php

I'm trying to use http_build_query and it's returning an unexpected string.  Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
$timestamp = time();

$args = array("name"=>"Bob",
              "id"=>uniqid(),
              "timestamp"=>$timestamp,
              "token"=>md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp));

$query = http_build_query($args, '', '&');

echo $query;
```

And this is the result:

```
name=Bob&id=5354a8336b3d7×tamp=1398057011&token=ba2c56005ac83d5169d173993f6a0d32
```

You can see that the key "timestamp" has been replaced with "×tamp" - I'm not even sure what that first character is because it is not the letter x.

I've tested this on several different servers with the same result.  What gives?!

Comment: Try to explore page source of output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in HTML `&times` translates to the [multiplication sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign); this is why you should escape HTML output.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($query, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```